# Angular Typed Forms Can't Assign To Partial Type

Tags: angular, angular-forms

[Made a basic example to show what I'm trying to accomplish:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kzaynn?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Basically given these two types:

```
type BaseType = FormGroup<{
  user: FormControl<string>;
}>;

type SomeOtherType = FormGroup<{
  user: FormControl<string>;
  amount: FormControl<number>;
}>;
```

I want to be able to pass `SomeOtherType` to a Component's input of type `BaseType` since they fulfill the contract.

Attempting this normally I get an seemingly backwards error:

```
Type 'SomeOtherType' is not assignable to type 'BaseType'.
Property 'amount' is missing in type '{ user: FormControl<string>; }' but required in type '{ user: FormControl<string>; amount: FormControl<number>; }'.
```

I can get wipe out all restrictions by using an input transform

```
@Input({ required: true, transform: (value: FormGroup): BaseType => value })
form!: BaseType;
```

But I don't like how then any form group can be passed when I want it restricted to objects that match the base type.

(To help head off any questions as to why not just do it some other way. This is part of an already finished product and I'm just trying to migrate it from the *untyped* forms **everywhere** to the new typed forms. With untyped forms, everything functions perfectly and the components that rely on a subset of the form controls have no issues, just hoping to be able to keep that functionality but while using the new typing features.)

Comment: `FormGroup` is a generic class itself and it is natural that `type FormA = FormGroup<A>` has nothing to do with `type FormB = FormGroup<B>` even though `A` has something to do with `B` (e.g. `A` is a base for `B`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something about the definition of FormGroup that doesn't allow covariance with a subtype of form controls.  In other words while `{user: FormControl, amount: FormControl}` is a subtype of `{user: FormControl}`, `FormGroup<{user: FormControl, amount: FormControl}>` ***IS NOT*** a subtype of `FormGroup<{user: FormControl>`.

*FormGroup* extends *AbstractControl* and it appears your problem is due to how the the value of the control is derived.  (This conclusion was reached by trial and error as the type gymnastics going on is inscrutable.)

Since the issue comes down to how *FormGroup* extends *AbstractControl*, we can use a discriminated union to make **BaseType** a bit more flexible while still maintaining pretty good type definitions.

```
type BaseTypeValue = {
  user: string;
};

type BaseTypeFormControls = { 
  [K in keyof BaseTypeValue]: FormControl<BaseTypeValue[K]> 
}

type BaseType = 
  FormGroup<BaseTypeFormControls>
  | AbstractControl<Partial<BaseTypeValue>, BaseTypeValue>;
```

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-drubuu?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Simply fantastic! This is exactly what I was hoping for where it still generates build errors when parent type provided isn't fulfilling all the needed properties base type contract, but the component doesn't have to be aware of the dozens of different models that will be using it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of your scenario, we can use the `|` operator of typescript to indicate that it can accept multiple types like below

```
@Input() formGroup!: BaseType | SomeOtherType;
```

This will get rid of your error, please find below a working stackblitz which highlights the key changes made!

main.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import {
  BaseType,
  ChildComponent,
  SomeOtherType,
} from './child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ChildComponent, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <app-child [formGroup]="formGroup"/>
    <app-child [formGroup]="formGroup1"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  formGroup: BaseType = new FormGroup({
    user: new FormControl<string | null>('asdf'),
  });
  formGroup1: SomeOtherType = new FormGroup({
    user: new FormControl<string | null>('asdf'),
    amount: new FormControl<number | null>(15),
  });
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

child.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

export type BaseType = FormGroup<{
  user: FormControl<string | null>;
}>;

export type SomeOtherType = FormGroup<{
  user: FormControl<string | null>;
  amount: FormControl<number | null>;
}>;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <input formControlName="user"/>
    <input *ngIf="isValidControl('amount')" type="number" formControlName="amount"/>
  </form>
  `,
  standalone: true,
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() formGroup!: BaseType | SomeOtherType;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  isValidControl(fieldName: string) {
    return (<FormGroup>this.formGroup)?.get(fieldName);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hyn8ss?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: While there's no denying this technically works. It requires the component to be aware (and import/depend) on every single type that might be be passed to it which is not a great option.